# Zend Framework 2 - AJAX Request from other server

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework2, cross-domain-policy

I have 2 domains (domain A, domain B).

On domain A is placed ZF2 application, and everything is ok.

On domain B is placed Landing Page (small site with form to collect data).

From Landing Page I want send form data to application on domain A (AJAX Request).

Unfortunatelly ZF2 app on domain A didn't receive data, and didn't show results. 
Everything is ok when I make AJAX Request from same domain where ZF2 app is.

I tried use JSONP but without success.

I don't have any other clue how to force this to work.

Answer (score 7):

As Bodgan's answer stated, this is a browser security issue rather than a ZF2 issue. One popular way to get around it is to change the `ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN` of your domain A to allow requests from domain B. This and other solutions are discussed on the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) page for [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control).

Basically you need to indicate to the receiving server (domain A) that it is okay to respond to requests for resources. You can do this within a `.htaccess` file placed in the web root of domain A. Below is some simple sample code that indicates to domain A that it should respond to resource sharing requests from all domains: `*`. The MDN article linked to above goes into a more in-depth discussion of "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)". Keep in mind that there are security implications, and in most scenarios you do not want to open up your server to requests from `*` origins, but rather to a specific host controlled by yourself.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Comment: This may also be done in php using the header() function, like so: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`, but keep in mind it must be called before any output is sent to the browser. See also: http://enable-cors.org/   and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains

Answer (score 0):

You could change your htaccess file to support but the easiest way would be to use the response class:

```
$this->_response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.http.response.html

If you are using json as your end point data source, use this in conjunction with the json helper which will set your encoding headers and a few other things too

```
$this->_helper->json->sendJson($jsonIsite);
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.json.introduction.html

there is https://github.com/zf-fr/zfr-cors for advanced CORS with ZF2 but a simple json endpoint with the above should work just fine.

Comment: In my example i have used a CORS wildcard * - make sure you do your research and use the appropriate domain for security

Answer (score -1):

Cross-domain ajax requests are forbidden due to security reasons (this is called Same origin policy). 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy