# Crossdomain ajax action in Zend Framework

Tags: php, ajax, apache, cross-domain

My application(A) needs to upload files by AJAX (Fineuploader library) to my subdomain(B) (physically other server).

What is my solution: set headers on B to allow requests from A. See this code of controller action:

```
public function imageAction()
{
    $this->_response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://' . Zend_Registry::get('config')->main_server->path);
    $this->_response->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');

    $this->_helper->json(array('test'));
}
```

Then I try to call this action by ajax from A. Request has the next headers:

```
Request URL:http://sub.domain.dev/upload/image
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-origin, x-mime-type, origin, x-requested-with, cache-control, x-file-name, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:sub.domain.dev
Origin:http://domain.dev
Referer:http://domain.dev
```

What I have done wrong? Thanks.

P.S.
When I send request with these headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Host:sub.domain.dev
Origin:http://domain.dev
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://domain.dev
```

Tho I think that problem in headers, sended by server.

Comment: crossdomain ajax? Have you heard of SOP?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609296/zend-framework-2-ajax-request-from-other-server

Comment: @Robert, sure, crossdomain ajax. Maybe you can help me? Its possible. But I have a War with these headers.

Comment: @Jon, thanks. I have setted these headers. But no luck: 403 Forbidden.

Comment: @plutov can you confirm you definitely don't get the 403 when making the request from a page on subdomain B? Given that the Origin headers are being set correctly it's worth making sure that the server isn't rejecting the request for a different reason (like the Request Method for example).

Comment: @Jon, yes. When I call this page from owner domain, I have correct headers.

Comment: I have found the reason. Apache return 403 access forbiden for OPTIONS method. How can I fix it?

Comment: @plutov Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934554/how-to-enable-and-use-http-put-and-delete-with-apache2-and-php

Comment: @Jon, thanks. I've found an answer. Noew i use CORS with new version of FineUploader. Thanks!

Comment: @plutov Great, please can you answer your own question and mark it as accepted? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use this jquery plugin [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) ?

[Document page about cross-domain uploads](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Cross-domain-uploads).

Comment: I use Fineuploader. But no matter. I think that problem in headers.